# What is the best strategy to win the Waterfall boss fight?

Tags: undertale

Which weapons, armor, and healing items are best for defeating

> Undyne the Undying in the Genocide Route?

Tips for bullet hell are also appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any tips for fighting Undyne the Undying?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320344/any-tips-for-fighting-undyne-the-undying)

Comment: @pppery the linked question is newer than this, would it be the opposite that that question is a duplicate of this?

Comment: I completely missed the date whe close voting; I have no strong opinion on which question is the canonical and which one is the duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the stuff, you can go for two strategies :

- [Cloudy Glasses](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Cloudy_Glasses) and [Torn Notebook](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Torn_Notebook). They have a low defense and attack power, though the invulnerability they offer is really useful during this battle, as she's attacking really fast. You can buy both of them in [Gerson](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Gerson)'s shop in the Waterfall.
- [Old Tutu](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Tutu) and [Ballet Shoes](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Ballet_Shoes). If you are a bit more comfortable with her patterns, those items will bring you the best attack and defense at this level of the game.

For healing items, try to avoid using your Butterscotch Pie and Snowman Pieces, because they will really be useful later. Just stock as much Cinnamon Bunny (from Snowdin Village's Shop) as you can, as it will heal 22 HP. You can also use the Abandoned Quiche, which heals 34 HP. Though it's an hidden item :

> In Waterfall by using flowers to reach the room to the right of the second flower puzzle room.

There is also the Sea Tea, an item which will heal you only 10 HP, but will increase the speed of your heart for the rest of the battle. You can buy it in Gerson's shop.

Now, the best strategy for this battle is to learn the patterns. The more you will fight her and remember her attacks, the easier it will become.